# Load data into textbox on selection of dropdown list

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a student management system project, where i am taking student enrollment form online using custom php apps.

When i am inserting enrollment form at the very first beginning of the form there is a drop down list of student iD. my client wants if he / she selects the ID of a particular student from the drop down list, his data will appear in to the text box automatically based on selection.

I know that here i require javascript but i am not sure how to do that.i have searched but didn't found any thing relevant exactly. Can any help me out.

Thanks

Comment: JS, AJAX, PHP, MYSQL will all be necessary

Comment: This is a Q&A site, we will not code for you.

Comment: have you tried a jQuery/Ajax solution? what you want has well documented solutions on the web, try some of them and then re-ask the question, btw welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: i haven't tried jquery / ajax solution though i know that this will be required to retrieve data from drop down selection to populate that on textbox based on selection. you dont need to code for me but a reference link would be enough.

Comment: may be the keywords i m using to find the solution on the web is not returning the exact one. so if you can help me with that would be enough and i would be grateful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to first capture the onchange event of the drop down list. When this event fires, you will need to run javascript that makes an AJAX call to the server in order to retrieve the student's data based on the selected student in the drop down list. You will need PHP/MySQL server side code to handle this request. When the AJAX call returns with the data, you will need more javascript to populate the textbox where you want the data displayed.

I won't write the code for you, but hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction.

Edit: If you need more details, lookup how to create an AJAX call in jQuery. Your requirements are not uncommon, so you should be able to find examples that are very near to what you need. See a relevent tutorial: [jQuery AJAX Tutorial](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks Will for your suggestion. I knew that i will require this but was not getting any point to start this. So you may suggest me any exact keyword or link to find out the exact solution. this might help me to figure out the solution immediately if you can at all.